# Container range based constructor efficiency

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl, set

While doing some test on an algorithm challenge website, I encountered this issue where my `std::unordered_set` was (somewhat marginally) slowing me down when using the range-base init:

```cpp
void test(vector<int>& nums1) {
    unordered_set<int> set1(nums1.begin(), nums1.end());
}
```

Is slower than

```cpp
vector<int> test(vector<int>& nums1) {
    unordered_set<int> set1;
    for (auto num : nums1) {
        set1.insert(num);
    }
}
```

How to explain this?

Comment: Please show your full benchmark code (including compiler optimization levels used), when asking about performance measuring.

Comment: where those 2 tested using the *same* data sets (i.e. nums1 was exactly the same in both benchmark tests, I mean not the size, but the content of the vector)?

Comment: Your second `test` has a non-`void` return type and doesn't `return`. It's also a discrepancy between the two functions. When benchmarking, try to keep everything exactly the same except for what you want to measure.

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple benchmark:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                          Time             CPU   Iterations
--------------------------------------------------------------------
from_range<int>/256            13998 ns        13998 ns        50128
from_inserts<int>/256          16543 ns        16542 ns        41822

from_range<int>/512            27573 ns        27573 ns        25060
from_inserts<int>/512          36691 ns        36691 ns        19426

from_range<int>/4096          246584 ns       246584 ns         2881
from_inserts<int>/4096        335115 ns       335111 ns         2111

from_range<int>/32768        2401152 ns      2401123 ns          291
from_inserts<int>/32768      3398496 ns      3398509 ns          204

from_range<int>/262144      29351062 ns     29351113 ns           23
from_inserts<int>/262144    52871572 ns     52871542 ns           12

from_range<int>/1048576    245771472 ns    245772469 ns            3
from_inserts<int>/1048576  445421451 ns    445415603 ns            2
```

[Source code](https://gist.github.com/eugnsp/8cdc4b18a2ac0c62c987c4f422afbebd)

Compiled with `g++ -O3 -m64 -march=native`, GCC version 8.3.0.